# Error in an android project

Tags: android

I made this temperature converter application, and the code is perfect. 
But whenever I run the AVD it shows the following errors:

```
[2012-06-05 12:22:58 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 1455
[2012-06-05 12:22:58 - Emulator] 
[2012-06-05 12:22:58 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2012-06-05 12:22:58 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: Are you sure the code is "perfect"? Or is it working? :P It's a difference. Joking aside, i believe you can specify the RAM given to the AVD. If you run android 4.0, you probably want to give 1024 or more.

Comment: Other applications are working appropriately?

Comment: Joey, yes its perfect ;) yes I use 4.0, lemme just try 1024 mb of RAM..

Comment: um.. i tried 1024mb of RAM, but still the same error

Comment: What's your AVD version?

Comment: I was using a 4.0, then used and 4.0.3, and now even tried on 3.0.. still the same error

Comment: If none of the solutions here work, in SO search, type Failed to allocate memory: 1455, it seems alot more people have your problem. I hope one of them provides the solution you need. Most talk about allocating RAM for the AVD. It depends on how much your system has.. Perhaps 512 should do.. If your screen displays "ANDROID" then things should work.. just wait. depending on machine it can take ages for it to be started.

Comment: Oh cool, then its fine.. Thx a lot Joey Roosing.!!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

I have the best and right solution proved according to the indications by Calvin in techarena forums.

- Click Start, click Run, type sysdm.cpl in the Open box, and then
  press ENTER.
- Click the Advanced tab, and then under Performance click Settings.
- Click the Advanced tab, and then under Virtual memory click Change.
- Under Drive [Volume Label], click the drive that contains the paging file that you want
  to change.
- Under Paging file size for selected drive, click Custom size, type a new paging file size in megabytes (MB) in the Initial size (MB) or Maximum size (MB) box, and then click Set.
- Click OK to close the dialog box and apply changes.

This usual error "Failed to allocate memory: 1455" would be caused by **Virtual Memory alocation**. After resolving in this way the allocation of Virtual Memory for the root C disk, you should read in the console of Eclipse, the following:

```
[2011-11-27 12:33:06 - Videotutorial1] ------------------------------
[2011-11-27 12:33:06 - Videotutorial1] Android Launch!
[2011-11-27 12:33:06 - Videotutorial1] adb is running normally.
[2011-11-27 12:33:06 - Videotutorial1] Performing com.videotutoriales.videotutorial1.Videotutorial1Activity activity launch
[2011-11-27 12:33:06 - Videotutorial1] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'VtAVD' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-11-27 12:33:06 - Videotutorial1] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'VtAVD'
[2011-11-27 12:33:39 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2011-11-27 12:33:39 - Emulator]
[2011-11-27 12:33:45 - Videotutorial1] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-11-27 12:33:45 - Videotutorial1] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-11-27 12:38:19 - Videotutorial1] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-11-27 12:38:19 - Videotutorial1] Uploading Videotutorial1.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-11-27 12:38:20 - Videotutorial1] Installing Videotutorial1.apk...
[2011-11-27 12:40:52 - Videotutorial1] Success!
[2011-11-27 12:40:53 - Videotutorial1] Starting activity com.videotutoriales.videotutorial1.Videotutorial1Activity on device emulator-5554
[2011-11-27 12:41:18 - Videotutorial1] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.videotutoriales.videotutorial1' on port 8628
```

**Solution 2:**

Open Android Virtual Device Manager and add or change the value to device ram size to 15 or a value smaller or higher:

[image]

Comment: First one did not help. Tried the second one, an emulator does appear, but its still stuck on a screen saying, "ANDROID"

Comment: If you want to test your app on a Android Emulator you'll have to wait for a few minutes while the new emulator loads.

Comment: http://androidbook.blogspot.in/2011/03/tip-speeding-up-your-android-emulator.html

Comment: This problem is surely for memory(RAM) allocation.Try increasing RAM (like 512).I had also experienced this but in my case it solved